# How to avoid InputMismatchException in java while taking input in int,char and int

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I am new to Java and I want to solve a simple problem in java.

In input I need to take an `integer a and then a character c and then another integer b` And print the output `if the character is '+' then print a+b` And so on like this.

The input looks like : `6+4`

But I find an error continuously like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

My Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    try {
        int a, b, ans = 0;
        char c;
        
        a = sc.nextInt();
        c = sc1.next().charAt(0);
        b = sc.nextInt();

        if (c=='+') {
            ans = a + b;
        } else if (c=='-') {
            ans = a - b;
        } else if (c=='*') {
            ans = a * b;
        } else if (c=='/') {
            ans = a / b;
        }

        System.out.println(ans);
    } finally {
        sc.close();
        sc1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: First up, you just need one `Scanner`, not two.  Secondly, _exactly_ what input are you providing?  Your program will only work if you have spaces between everything, for example `2 + 3`, not `2+3`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I need to take `2+3` input like this

Comment: Then you'll probably need to read it into a single `String` then go looking for the part that isn't a number.  It's possible with a `Scanner` but kind of awkward.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if you don't mind will you provide the answer. Since I am new and so I have less Idea about java :(

Comment: as @DawoodibnKareem said next() and nextInt() keep reading till it count the first white space (space - tab - new line - so any thing that classified as space )

Comment: many many thanks. both of you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an eval() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java)

Comment: @LearningMathematics I think this is not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the double scanner object and try this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a, b, ans = 0;
    String c;
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)([+*/-])([0-9]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid command");
    } else {
        a = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
        c = matcher.group(2);
        b = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(3));

        if (c.equals("+")) {
            ans = a + b;
        } else if (c.equals( "-")) {
            ans = a - b;
        } else if (c.equals( "*")) {
            ans = a * b;
        } else if (c.equals("/")) {
            ans = a / b;
        }

        System.out.println(ans);
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly.But can you explain that why we use `charAt(1)` in char and `charAt(2)` in int value?

Comment: for example
1+2 is the input 
so the first char will be 1 so input.charAt(0) will be for first number and 1 for the sign  and 2 for the 2nd number 
Character.getNumericValue used to get the int value of that char as charAt return char and if you used it directly like this
a = input.charAt(0) i will make a equal the unit code value of whatever exist at 0 which we do not want 
try to use this and see the difference

Comment: if I put `7+54` then the output should be `61` but is shows `12` :( how to solve this?

Comment: try to use regex as the updated version that i just did check my answer again

Comment: i use jdk 11 and intelljidea ide did you used the new answer and what the output you get

Comment: Thanks :) I see your edited code and now it's work for me perfectly :) thanks . +1 for this solution :)